# Расстояние от иконки до текста

Tags: html, css, responsive

У меня есть текст, и когда я нажимаю на иконку `+` он разворачивается, когда на `-` он сворачивается. Вопрос в том, как сделать отступ сверху, чтобы иконки `+` и `-` были чуть ниже, чем текст, и в центре?
Вот html:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
<input id="read-more-state-1" class="read-more-state" type="checkbox">
<span class="read-more-target">
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages.
</span>
<label for="read-more-state-1" class="read-more-button">
<span class="read-more-button-icon"></span>
</label>
</p>
```

Вот CSS:

```
.read-more-state {
  display: none;
}

.read-more-button {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {   
  .read-more-target {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    transition: .25s ease;
  }

  .read-more-button {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background: url(img/arrow%20grad.svg);
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .read-more-state:checked + .read-more-target {
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: inherit;
  }

  .read-more-state:checked ~ .read-more-button {
    background: url(img/arrow%20up%20grad.svg);
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.read-more-button {
    display: block;
    margin: 1em auto 0;
}
```

1. Сделать кнопку `display: block;` вместо `display: inline-block;`, чтобы переносилось на следующую строку;
2. При помощи маргина отцентровать значением `auto` и добавить сверху отступ `1em`.

Comment: спасибо большое! отметил как верный!